# ServiceWorker registration.update() not seeing updates

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm new to ServiceWorkers and am trying to figure out how to check for application updates manually in a `create-react-app`. We created a custom class to replace [but based on] the `registerServiceWorker.js` file. We have a test button that will run `registration.update()`.

This class is added to the mobx provider and injected into the home component where the button is that I'm using to manually run the `updateServiceWorker()` method.

While on an already open tab - after a deployment - I click the button that runs `updateServiceWorker`. I see the three console logs in that function, but the `handleOnUpdateFound` function doesn't run. If I then go click the `Update` link in Chrome > Dev Tools > Application > Service Workers, the `handleOnUpdateFound` callback is executed and the messages we have observing the booleans show as expected.

What would be different from what we're doing in this class to update vs what Chrome is doing?

Here's the class:

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';

export interface IAppStateService {
    isLocalhost: boolean;
    registerServiceWorker();
    unregisterServiceWorker();
    updateServiceWorker();
}

export class AppStateService implements IAppStateService {
    @observable installingUpdate: boolean = false;
    @observable updateInstalled: boolean = false;
    @observable isOfflineMode: boolean = false;

    public get isLocalhost(): boolean {
        return Boolean(
            window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
            // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
            window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
            // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
            window.location.hostname.match(
                /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
            )
        );
    }

    public registerServiceWorker() {
        console.log('registerServiceWorker', process.env);

        // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
        const publicUrl = new URL(
            process.env.PUBLIC_URL!,
            window.location.toString()
        );

        if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
            // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
            // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
            // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
            return;
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

            if (this.isLocalhost) {
                // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
                this.checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);

                // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
                // service worker/PWA documentation.
                navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
                    console.log(
                        'This web app is being...'
                    );
                });
            } else {
                // Is not local host. Just register service worker
                this.registerValidSW(swUrl);
            }
        });
        // }
    }

    public unregisterServiceWorker(): void {
        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
                registration.unregister();
            });
        }
    }

    public updateServiceWorker(): void {
        console.log('updateServiceWorker', navigator.serviceWorker);

        if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
                console.log('checking for an update...');
                registration.update().then(() => {
                    console.log('...done checking for an update');
                });
            });
        }
    }

    private checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl: string) {
        this.isOfflineMode = false;

        // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
        fetch(swUrl)
            .then(response => {
                // console.log('checkValidServiceWorker', response);
                // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
                if (
                    response.status === 404 ||
                    response.headers.get('content-type')!.indexOf('javascript') === -1
                ) {
                    // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
                    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
                        registration.unregister().then(() => {
                            window.location.reload();
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
                    this.registerValidSW(swUrl);
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
                this.isOfflineMode = true;
            });
    }

    private registerValidSW(swUrl: string) {
        return navigator.serviceWorker
            .register(swUrl)
            .then(registration => {
                registration.onupdatefound = this.handleOnUpdateFound;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
            });
    }

    @action private handleOnUpdateFound = (): void => {
        console.log('handleOnUpdateFound'); 

        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
            console.log('handleOnUpdateFound 2', registration); 

            const installingWorker = registration.installing;

            if (installingWorker) {
                this.installingUpdate = true;

                installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
                    if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
                        // console.log('navigator', navigator);
                        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                            // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
                            // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
                            // It's the perfect time to display a 'New content is
                            // available; please refresh.' message in your web app.
                            // console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');

                            setTimeout(() => {
                                window.location.reload();
                            // tslint:disable-next-line:align
                            }, 7000);

                        } else {
                            // At this point, everything has been precached.
                            // It's the perfect time to display a
                            // 'Content is cached for offline use.' message.
                            // console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
                        }

                        this.updateInstalled = true;
                        this.installingUpdate = false;
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did more troubleshooting and the main reason this wasn't working was the `Cache-Control: public,max-age=0` needed to be set (it wasn't zero before). Chrome's DevTools must be doing something to bypass that.